# How do I separate an enum type?

Tags: c#, enums

I have the following type listed:

```
using System;

namespace Music
{
 [Flags]
    public enum Days
    {
        None = 0,
        Mon = 1,
        Tue = 2,
        Wed = 4,
        Thu = 8,
        Fri = 16,
        Sat = 32,
        Sun = 64

    }
 }
```

I want you to, in two variables of Days, for example:

```
Days myDays1 = Days.Mon | Days.Thu | Days.Fri | Days.Sat;
Days myDays2 = Days.Mon | Days.Tue | Days.Sat;
```

Using `myDays1 & myDays2` I want to get the days that match but separately so I can check other things, that is, I want to have `Days.Mon` on one side and `Days.Sat` on the other. How can I do this?

Comment: I don't follow your question I'm afraid. What do you mean by "on one side" and "on the other"?

Comment: I want to get the myDays1 & myDays2 in a variable and then go through all the coincidences. @canton7

Comment: You already know how to get `myDays1 & myDays2` in a variable: `Days result = myDays1 & myDays2`. If you want to list which days are selected in `result`, see @SomeBody's answer: loop through each day, see whether it's set in `result`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this fairly easily using Linq. Given your existing declaration of `myDays1` and `myDays2`:

```
var overlap = Enum.GetValues<Days>().Where(day => (myDays1 & myDays2 & day) != 0);

foreach (var day in overlap)
{
    ... Do something with 'day', which is of type 'Days' (Mon and Sat for your example)
```

Comment: @JuanDomínguez What version of .Net/C# are you using? `GetValues<TEnum>()` requires .Net 5..0 or later.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this extension method to get the days separated:

```
public static IEnumerable<Days> GetSingleDays(this Days input)
        {
            return ((Days[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(Days))).Where(x => x != Days.None && input.HasFlag(x));
        }
```

If you write

```
Days myDays1 = Days.Mon | Days.Thu | Days.Fri | Days.Sat;
Days myDays2 = Days.Mon | Days.Tue | Days.Sat;
Days and = myDays1 & myDays2;
Days[] single = and.GetSingleDays().ToArray();
```

you'll get an array which contains Days.Mon and Day.Sat;

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm misunderstanding you, you want all the matches between the two variables while still being able to determine which days were matched? Since your flag enum is basically a bitmask, you can use a bitwise AND to get a new enum that has all the matches.

```
Days myDays1 = Days.Mon | Days.Thu | Days.Fri | Days.Sat;
Days myDays2 = Days.Mon | Days.Tue | Days.Sat;
var matches = myDays1 & myDays2;
// matches.Mon == True, matches.Sat == True
// matches > 0 == True
```

Answer (score -1):

Try following  :

```
            Days myDay = Days.Sat;

            Days myDays1 = Days.Mon | Days.Thu | Days.Fri | Days.Sat;
            Days myDays2 = Days.Mon | Days.Tue | Days.Sat;

            if (((int)myDays2 & (int)myDay) != 0)
            {
            }
```